# Does the series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{(n+1)^a} \ n\in \mathbb N, a>0$ always diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the following series always diverge?

> $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{(n+1)^a} 
> \ n\in \mathbb N, a>0$$

Comment: What about Dirichlet's test?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$(n+1)^a-n^a=n^a(1+1/n)^a-n^a=n^a(1+a/n+a(a-1)/n^2+...)-n^a=an^{a-1}+a(a-1)n^{a-2}+...$$

then

$$\frac{((n+1)^a-n^a)}{(n+1)^a}\sim \frac a n+a(a-1)n^{-2}+...$$

therefore the given series diverges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1n$.

Answer (score 2):

By the mean value theorem,
$(n+1)^a-n^a
=ax^{a-1}$
where $n < x < n>1$.
Therefore each term is at least 
$an^{a-1}/(n+1)^a
\approx a/n$
since $(1+1/n)^a \to 1$.
The sum of these diverges.